# How does java handle multithreading? more threads than processes

Tags: java, multithreading, parallel-processing

I was wondering if anyone can tell me how java handles multithreading when you have more threads than the cores? for example, I have a quad core but my program is using 8 threads.

I'm just asking because I want to do some parallel programming. I want to use it to improve performance in an array.

thanks for any help.

Edit:
Just to clarify, I'm going to be using parallel programming to devide an array by the number of cores. so I have an array of about 50K and the hope is to use PP to improve performance and increase the array size.

Comment: And I have a performance test script that creates 1000 threads. One CPU can run multiple threads, but as I understand, only one thread can occupy a CPU at one time (but 2 threads can run on 2 CPUs at the same time). The OS handles the distribution of resources (CPU usage, RAM, etc...). It has nothing to do with the language, though.

Comment: However, even with 1 CPU, multithreading is still faster generally.

Comment: @btquanto Unless your CPU has 1000 cores (or 500 cores with hyperthreading), starting 1000 threads is not going to make your program run faster. Most of those threads will be waiting until they are scheduled. Just adding more threads is not automatically going to make the program run faster.

Comment: @Jesper Since the threads are scheduled by the OS, it doesn't run only your program's threads. Let's say the OS has 9000 threads running, and your program just adds 1000 more threads, if I assume each of the threads has the same priority, doesn't it mean just your program occupies 10% of the resources in total?

Comment: @btquanto No. It depends on what the threads are doing. If those 9000 OS threads are waiting for I/O, then your application threads might use 99% of the CPU at that point in time.

Comment: Google for "preemptive multitasking."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> can let me know how java handles multithreading

It doesn't (Unless you have green threads, and most likley you don't). The OS does the scheduling.

> I have a quad core but my program is using 8 threads.

If you have hyperthreading, they can all be running at once.  BTW You are likely to have 1 thread per CPU just for the GC, and many others besides even if you haven't created any yourself.

> I want to do some parallel programming. wanting to use it to improve performance in an array

I suggest you keep the number of busy threads the the number of logical CPUs you have.  In fact there is a library which helps you do this builtin e.g. [DoubleStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/DoubleStream.html)

```
double[] manyDoubles = ....
DoubleSummaryStatistics dss =
            DoubleStream.of(manyDouble)
                        .parallel()// do stuff in parallel using all the CPUS
                        .filter(x -> x >= 1)
                        .map(x -> x * x)
                        .summaryStatistics();
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. the quad core and 8 threads was an example, just to help explain my point. but thanks for the help :) think i understand. thanks you

Comment: @DatAssKyle start with parallel streams first if you can.  This will efficiently use all the CPUs you have and the code will be much simpler as well.